# How to display by default value 0.00 in angular 4 for input type="number"?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular4-forms

I want the  users to see the following "0.00" in the text-box of type number.This is the following HTML i am using:-

```
 **<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0.00">[(ngModel)]="_vendorDetailsDTO.openingBalance" step="0.01" name="bal" #bal="ngModel">**
```

In code behind during the page load i am assigning the value 0.00 as shown below.

> this._vendorDetailsDTO.openingBalance = 0.00;

But still in the user interface it displays 0.
I am using Angular 4 and primeng version is 4.2.2?I am very new to these technology,any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pipe **`Number`**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0.00">[(ngModel)]="'_vendorDetailsDTO.openingBalance | number: 2'" step="0.01" name="bal" #bal="ngModel">
```